# Calculating complex numbers with rational exponents

Tags: java, math, complex-numbers

Yesterday I created this piece of code that could calculate z^n, where z is a complex number and n is any positive integer.

```
--snip--
float real = 0;
float imag = 0;

// d is the power the number is raised to [(x + yi)^d]
for (int n = 0; n <= d; n++) {
  if (n == 0) {
    real += pow(a, d);
  } else { // binomial theorem      
    switch (n % 4) {
      case 1: // i
        imag += bCo(d, n) * pow(a, d - n) * pow(b, n);
        break;
      case 2: // -1
        real -= bCo(d, n) * pow(a, d - n) * pow(b, n);
        break;
      case 3: // -i
        imag -= bCo(d, n) * pow(a, d - n) * pow(b, n);
        break;
      case 0: // 1
        real += bCo(d, n) * pow(a, d - n) * pow(b, n);
        break;
    }
  }
}
--snip--

int factorial(int n) {
  int total = 1;
  for (int i = n; i > 1; i--) { total *= i; }
  return total;
}

// binomial cofactor
float bCo(int n, int k) {
  return (factorial(n)/(factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)));
}
```

I use the binomial theorem to expand z^n, and know whether to treat each term as a real or imaginary number depending on the power of the imaginary number.

What I want to do is to be able to calculate z^n, where n is any positive real number (fractions). I know the binomial theorem can be used for powers that aren't whole numbers, but I'm not really sure how to handle the complex numbers. Because i^0.1 has a real and imaginary component I can't just sort it into a real or imaginary variable, nor do I even know how to program something that could calculate it.

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can help me accomplish this, or maybe even a better way to handle complex numbers that will make this possible?

Oh, I'm using java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a complex number [image: z] such that [image: z = x + iy].

Thus, the polar form of [image: z] is = [image: re^itheta], where:

- [image: r] is the magnitude of [image: z], or [image: sqrt(x2+y2)], and
- [image: theta] is [image: atan y over x].

Once you have done so, you can use [DeMoivre's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to calculate [image: z^n] like so:

> [image: z^n = r^n e^i n theta]

or more simply as

> [image: z^n = r^n (cos (n theta) + i sin(n theta))]

For more information read up on the [polar form of a complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

I actually learnt about DeMoivre's Theorem last semester at school, so I feel a bit silly for not thinking to use it.

Comment: See also `public Complex pow(double e)` http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/number/Complex.html

Comment: "z = r*e*i*theta" on the third line should be "z = r*e^(i*theta)"  I'd change it myself, but I don't have the rep for that yet.

Comment: The formula is valid only for integer values of n

Comment: +1 this is what I was going to answer.  Though DeMoivre's theorem is only valid for integer `n`, [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) gives you the result that lies between the last and second-to-last step, which is valid for all real/complex n.  Note that, like `sqrt()`, it only gives *one* of the roots.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, it may have multiple solutions. See [Wikipedia: Complex number / exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

> Similar considerations show that we can define rational real powers just as for the reals, so *z*<sup>1/n</sup> is the *n*:th root of *z*. Roots are not unique, so it is already clear that complex powers are multivalued, thus careful treatment of powers is needed; for example (8<sup>1/3</sup>)<sup>4</sup> ≠ 16, as there are three cube roots of 8, so the given expression, often shortened to 8<sup>4/3</sup>, is the simplest possible.

I think you should break it down to polar notation and go from there.

Comment: In addition to the above link, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Failure_for_non-integer_powers and section 12.1.1 in http://www.suitcaseofdreams.net/De_Moivre_formula.htm

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Polar notation should make it a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at math, so probably I understood your task wrong. But as far as I got it - apache commons math can help you: http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/complex.html

Example:

```
Complex first  = new Complex(1.0, 3.0);
Complex second = new Complex(2.0, 5.0);

Complex answer = first.log();        // natural logarithm.
        answer = first.cos();        // cosine
        answer = first.pow(second);  // first raised to the power of second
```

Answer (score 0):

a^n is ill defined when n is not an integer and a is not a positive number.

If z is a complex number, you can still give a meaning to z^a = exp(a log z) but you have to figure out what log z means when z is not a positive number.

And there is [no unique choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).